# MVVM WPF - Implement current_user like Ruby on Rails

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm creating a new WPF application with (my first WPF app):

- .Net 4.0
- MVVM Light
- C#
- MahApps Metro

I've started with the Login View (Hehe, obvious right?). Well, I'd like to preserve information of the current user logged into the app so I can hide/show elements based on the profile and some other similar tasks.

I'm familiar with Ruby on Rails/MVC and Devise. In Devise you have the current_user object along all the project and you can use it for several purposes.

I know that MVC and MVVM are somewhat different concepts so, I don't know for sure if the same approach is valid for MVVM/WPF.

Is it valid? If so, how can I do it with MVVM Light?

Comment: Do you use a DI container? If so, register a singleton service and put the user information there. Otherwise, if you prefer ugly code, create a static class, that's basically the same, but not testable because you can't mock it away.

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal is where this information is kept, as it flows with the execution context of the thread.

Comment: Thanks @Haukinger that's what I ended doing.